# How can I format date in x-date-picker?

Tags: mui-x-data-grid, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I've tried to use

- format="l"
- format="m/d/yyyy"

I want this format `m/d/yyyy`, I mean I'd like the day and the month without zeroes. How I do that?

P.S.: I am using this datepicker in the material UI datagrid.

I tried to check in the dayjs/datepicker documentation.

Check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-waterfall-nsx3dt?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: You should include minimal reproducable code and it's in the guide [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](How do I ask a good question) . It's there for a reason - also you should add information what's failing exactly in your code.

Comment: What is not working? How can we help when we don't see possible mistake?

Comment: It's not removing zeroes. I said. M/D/YYYY is the same as MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: As I said, nobody is able to figure out mistake in invisible code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-waterfall-nsx3dt?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding zero from the beginning there's date field prop `shouldRespectLeadingZeros`, here [the link to mui documentation on that](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/#respect-leading-zeros-in-fields)

```
<DatePicker 
  label="Helper text example" 
  format="M/D/YYYY"
  slotProps={{ field: { shouldRespectLeadingZeros: true } }}
/>
```